# Updating UILabel Returns Null?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel, updating

I'm trying to update a label that display the amount of coins, stored in `NSUserDefaults`.

I have a method called updateCoins which I call when I have added, coins based on user activity, to update the `UILabel`:

```
- (void)updateCoins {
    self.coinsLabel.text = 
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 
       [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Coins"] intValue]];
    NSLog(@"Label: %@", self.coinsLabel.text);
    NSLog(@"Coins: %d", 
       [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Coins"] intValue]);
}
```

However in the logger, I get the following:

```
Label: (null)
Coins: 10
```

The thing is when, I call this method in `viewWillAppear`, it updates the app, when transitioning to a different `UIViewController` and coming back.

If it helps I'm updating the object the following way:

```
int coins;
coins = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Coins"] intValue];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",coins+10] forKey:@"Coins"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[self updateCoins];
```

Comment: what is this? "self.treeCoinsLabel.text"

Comment: You are setting intvalue to "self.coinsLabel.text". but you are outputting "self.treeCoinsLabel.text" in the logger.

Comment: use [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey, you will get rid of stringwithformat stuff.

Comment: Oops typo! They are both self.coinsLabel.text.

Comment: What do you see in the logger when NSLog self.coinsLabel? Is it nil as well?

Comment: Is `coinsLabel` connected with `IBOutlet`?

Comment: @crzyonez777 I also get (null) hmm...

Comment: Are you sure you initialized UILabel in the first place? self.coinsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

Comment: @Akhilrajtr Yeah it is, I am using subclass of UILabel (i.e. VALabel) which I declared as @ property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet VALabel *coinsLabel; and I also entered THLabel under custom class in storyboard.

Comment: @user1886754 is it `THLabel` or `VALabel`?

Comment: VALabel** Sorry it's really late.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.coinsLabel.text = // replace this with self.treeCoinsLabel.text
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 
  [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Coins"] intValue]];
NSLog(@"Label: %@", self.treeCoinsLabel.text);
```

Also if your self.coinsLabel is an outlet, verify that it's correctly connected on the user interface, if not you must allocate it before use it.

Comment: Thank you bsarr007! I accidentally typed it incorrectly on here. I used to call it treeCoinsLabel but they are both self.coinsLabel.text

Comment: Also if your self.coinsLabel is an outlet, verify that it's correctly connected on the user interface, if not you must allocate it before use it.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you are assigning the value to the `self.coinsLabel.text` before its get **allocated**(pointer which holds other custom UILabel) , that's why it gets updated when come back from the child UIViewController.

Ensure that the `UILabel` has allocated before assign the value to it. you might calling this function before the View gets loaded.

Comment: What's the best way of doing this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: BTW it's all happening in the same view controller.

Comment: When you are coming back from childViewController, check there whether allocating the custom label

Comment: Yes, Happening in the same Class. but the flow seems like missing initialisation

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities in this situation.

self.coinsLabel is null and not initialized. 
 If `self.coinsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];` doing this in `- (void)viewDidLoad` is still nill then you should check `Is it connected from storyboard to class?`.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad:animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad:animated];
    self.coinsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
}
```

I guess you forget initializing UILabel.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I'm still getting (null)

Comment: I'm not familiar with storyboard, so... I don't know how to solve your problem anymore :(